# OS X 10.11 El Capitan - Verifying file dialog, every time a file is opened

Tags: bug, ui, macos

Not sure, if this question will be closed, but the situation is quite annoying.

Every time, I open some .pdf or .jpg file, a dialog appears,and it seems to be stuck there for a long time. After I click on close button, and open the file again, it opens without the dialog.

[image: Verifying file dialog OS X 10.11 El Capitan Beta]

Comment: Please include the exact build version so we can best help you

Comment: I have the same issue, with .doc, .saver (screensaver), even some folders would open with the Verifying dialog.

Comment: maybe run first aid from disk utility to see if there's any issue? also, judging from the logo, which is the security & privacy preference panel, do you have filevault encryption turned on?

Answer (score 6):

The cause *might* be that the file/folder was downloaded.

In any case, you can remove the 'quarantine' status with

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "/path/to/Geometry.pdf"`

you can add the `-r` flag to make it recursive, in case you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I have this when opening a VMWare folder `Virtual Machines.localized` and not sure why it is happening.

It seems to coincide with the following log:

```
11/11/15 09:59:14.044 CoreServicesUIAgent[4730]: Error -60005 creating authorization
```

Also, when I do a Cmd-I to view the folder info, there was a user that was stuck as "Fetching..." in the permissions list. Removing it and applying permissions down did nothing.

I moved the files in that folder out into a new folder, deleted the one with the issue, and renamed it back and everything is fine now. Go figure.